# API Fetch with reactjs and show into graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get city names and their respective tempratures from https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/air-temperature and then show it to Graphs. So, How I can get all the cities names and set it to labels inside graph code?  Below is my code. I am new to reactjs. So, any kind of help will be highly appropriated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {},
      areas: [],
      temperature: [],
      all: {}
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/air-temperature")
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          all: res.data,
          areas: res.data.metadata.stations,
          temperature: res.data.items[0].readings
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    this.getChartData();
  }
  getChartData() {
    console.log("length", this.state.areas);
    // Ajax calls here
    this.setState({
      chartData: {
        labels: [
          "Boston",
          "Worcester",
          "Springfield",
          "Lowell",
          "Cambridge",
          "New Bedford"
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Population",
            data: [617594, 181045, 153060, 106519, 105162, 95072],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    //console.log(this.state.areas);
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "relative", width: 500, height: 500 }}>
        <h1>Chart</h1>
        <Line data={this.state.chartData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: What do you mean get "name" from `areas`? Also can you include a sample of what `areas` looks like?

Comment: Basically I want to fetch all "names" from this API and then set it to "labels" under chartDate function.
Main purpose is to show graph with cities names and their tempratures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/air-temperature")
      .then(res =>{
        this.getChartData(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  }
  getChartData( data) {
    const cityNames = data.metadata.stations.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc,cur.name],[]);
    const temperatures = data.items[0].readings.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc,cur.value],[])
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      chartData: {
        labels: cityNames,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Population",
            data: temperatures,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)",
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.state.areas);
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "relative", width: 500, height: 500 }}>
        <h1>Chart</h1>
        <Line data={this.state.chartData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-silence-ykcqj

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` method of the `areas` array to iterate over the elements in `areas` and get the name of each.

For example (data taken from the [given API endpoint](https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/air-temperature), specifically `data.metadata.stations`):

```js
const areas = [
    { id: 'S117',
    device_id: 'S117',
    name: 'Banyan Road',
    location: { latitude: 1.256, longitude: 103.679 } },
    { id: 'S50',
    device_id: 'S50',
    name: 'Clementi Road',
    location: { latitude: 1.3337, longitude: 103.7768 } },
    { id: 'S107',
    device_id: 'S107',
    name: 'East Coast Parkway',
    location: { latitude: 1.3135, longitude: 103.9625 } },
]

const areaNames = areas.map(e => e.name);
```

With result for `areaNames`:

```js
[ 'Banyan Road', 'Clementi Road', 'East Coast Parkway' ]
```

Comment: I am trying above code. But it is showing zero records in array.

Comment: Where have you put the `areaNames` line? And on which render is it empty? because it will be empty on at least the first render.

Comment: @AMobin yeah, `areas` won't have been set yet since it gets set asynchronously. Since `areaNames` is computed and you store the raw data, you shouldn't store it as well. Instead, move the definition of `areaNames` to the `render` method—or to a method called by `render`. That or change `componentDidMount` to be an `async` method and `await` the `axios.get` call.

Answer (score 0):

your getChartData() function will be called when even data has not come from backend
so keep a flag fetching
so if its true
return from functions and dont show chart
show it when fetching is false and fetched is true